# Catching an ExternalInterface call to a non-existing function

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3

I have about 1000 SWF files all calling JavaScript functions through `ExternalInterface`.

I do not have access to these files source files, and have no way of editing them.

My basic problem is that that they are all calling different functions and the Flash AS3 script hangs until it gets a response from the function.

What I am hoping to do is detect what the functions which are being called from the SWF files in JavaScript and then create the function on the fly, however, in order to do that I would need to detect the function being called first.

Is there any way to do this in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible in JavaScript.

Comment: Really? So it is not possible to detect a `ReferenceError` and handle it without using a `try {} catch () {}`? Not even with custom event handlers, by prototyping the ReferenceError object?

Comment: All errors should be catchable, use UncaughtErrorEvent in actionscript 3 or window.onerror in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

1. I dont know how much variation there is, but is it an option to use a decompiler on several swf's just to see which ExternalInterface calls are called? Try online decompiler http://www.showmycode.com/
2. You can catch undefined errors from Flash using `UncaughtErrorEvent`
   http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/UncaughtErrorEvent.html
3. I dont'tknow if javascript is throwing errors? You could catch the errors from javascript too, using `window.onerror` 
   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onerror

Answer (score -1):

Could you explain how much control you have over the SWF files and what exactly is it you want to achieve?

Are these AS2 ou AS3 ? 
Is there a main SWF file loading these SWF files ?

I was looking at the docs and it seems that using `ExternalInterface.marshallExceptions` in conjunction with `UnhandledErrorEvent`, you may detect unexisting function calls from the Flash side.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#marshallExceptions

Comment: As I stated in the question, I have no access to the SWF source files, I just need to handle any EI functions they are calling on JavaScript.

Comment: Not having the source does not mean you don't have control over the SWF files. For instance if you are loading them inside another SWF you may be able to use the `ExternalInterface.marshallExceptions`. Also, there are several tools out there to inspect/modify SWF bytecode. So, I don't understand your down vote.